# Multiple clash royale accounts on 1 iOS device?

Tags: clash-royale

Is is possible to play two clash royale accounts from a single iOS device? I want to play for my friend while my account is unlocking chests. I logged into his Apple ID account on my Game Center on my device, but it still loads the progress from my game, even when launching the game from Game Center and restarting the device.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you can.

I just read up on this, and if you have multiple game centre id's then you can use multiple accounts by signing out of the account, and into the new account.

More information at the following url

http://clashroyalearena.com/tutorials/play-2-clash-royale-accounts

Answer (score 0):

You need to erase the game's data from your device's Settings, or reinstall it. **MAKE SURE THAT YOU FIRST LOGGED YOUR GAME OUT OF THE GAME CENTER.** Then, restart the game. At the first opportunity, log into your new Game Center Account.